# Connection between bijective maps and subsets of product sets in a multi-variable problem

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set. A bijective map $f: X\to X$ can be represented by a subset $A$ of $X\times X$, such that for every element $a\in X$ there is only one element $b$ so that $(a,b)\in A$, and similarly the other way around.

Now we want to generalize this, and look at subsets of multiple products of the set $X$, and considering different ways of how a subset can represent a bijective map.

The simplest new case is when we have $X^4$, and we want to get bijective maps $X^2\to X^2$. The problem to solve is to find all subsets $A\in X^4$, so that it describes bijective maps in two ways. If we denote variables as $(a,b,c,d)\in X^4$ then the subset $A$ should be such that it gives bijective maps in the directions $(a,b)\to (c,d)$ but also $(a,d)\to (c,b)$.

What is the name for such a subset and the different ways of organizing it into bijective maps? I don't really know where to look for such solutions.

The more difficult problem is when we want to go to even bigger products. A problem which came up is to look at subsets of $X^6$ and consider three ways of organizing the subset into a bijective map $X^3\to X^3$. Using variables $(a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ we would want to have a bijective map in the directions $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\to (b_1,b_2,b_3)$, $(b_1,a_2,a_3)\to (a_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $(a_1,b_2,a_3)\to (b_1,a_2,b_3)$. If you wish, these are ``partial transpose'' operations, and we would want to have a bijective map in all directions.

A trivial solution is when the map $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\to (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is the identity on $X^3$, this map satisfies also the other requirements. Are there any other solutions? Is this known, perhaps in some other disguise?

**Update:** If we know solution to the problem on $X^4$, then it can be used to get a trivial solution on $X^6$: the map $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\to (b_1,b_2,b_3)$ should be for example identity on the first variable, and the non-trivial bijective map on the second and third. But how to construct solutions that are not of this form?

Comment: What would be an example of a subset of $X^4$ or $X^6$, say with $X=\{u,v\}$ or $\{u,v,w\}$, representing a bijection on $X^2$ (or $X^3$) but one of the partial transpositions is *not* a bijection?

Comment: The simplest counter-example is the permutation map on $X^2$. So for any pair $(a,b)$ the map gives $(b,a)$. It is clearly a bijection. But if you do the partial transpose like I wrote, you don't even get a well-defined map!

Comment: If I understand correctly, with $X = \{u,v\}$, a map on $X^2$ that does work is the cyclic map on $X^2$ given by $(u,u) \mapsto (u,v) \mapsto (v,u) \mapsto (v,v) \mapsto (u,u)$. Transposing $(a,b) \mapsto (c,d)$ into $(a,d) \mapsto (c,b)$ gives $(u,v) \mapsto (u,u) \mapsto (v,v) \mapsto (v,u) \mapsto (u,v)$, the inverse of the original map. Another one that doesn't work is $(u,u) \mapsto (u,u)$, $(u,v) \mapsto (v,u) \mapsto (v,v) \mapsto (u,v)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree! Let $N$ be the cardinality of $X$. An other example for $N=2$ is 

$(u,v)\leftrightarrow (v,u)$ and $(u,u)\leftrightarrow (v,v)$

So we have two 2-cycles.

I have more examples for $N=3$ and $N=4$, obviously there are more possibilities there. 

So far I have no non-trivial examples for the problem on $X^3$, perhaps I will just write a brute force code first, for $N=2$.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the concept of an [orthogonal array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_array) Specifically a $t-(v,k,1)$ orthogonal array which has $k$ columns and $v^t$ rows filled with $v$ symbols in such a way that any $t$ columns contain each ordered $t$-tuple once. That article gives a $2- (4,5,1)$ example.

In your setup that is a $16$ element subset of $X^5$ with $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ so that you can read it $120$ ways to get a bijection from $X^2$ to $X^2$ such as by interpreting $(a,b,c,d,e)$ as $(e,c)\rightarrow  (a,d)$.

**LATER**

Here are a couple of solutions for $X^6$ , The first might satisfy you or you might feel it is just your identity example in disguise:

Take three permutations $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of $X$ and then these sextuples $$(u,v,w,\alpha u,\beta v,  \gamma w)$$
This gives what you want and one more: 
Using variables $(a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ we would have a bijective map in the directions $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\to (b_1,b_2,b_3)$, $(b_1,a_2,a_3)\to (a_1,b_2,b_3)$ and $(a_1,b_2,a_3)\to (b_1,a_2,b_3)$. And also $(a_1,a_2,b_3)\to (b_1,b_2,a_3)$.

In the case that $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the identity map, all four of these are the identity map on $X^3.$

---

If you take odd $n$ and the sextuples $$(u,v,w,u+v,v+w,w+u) \mod n$$ for $X=\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}.$ You get less than a full orthogonal array but $17$ of the $20$ ways to pick three positions work, including the ones you want.

This is essentially multiplying vectors $\left( \begin{array}{c} u\\ v\\ w \end{array} \right)$in $X^3$ by the matrix $$M=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0 \\0&0&1\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 1&0&1 \end{array}\right)$$

The choices which work correspond to the triples of rows giving a matrix with an inverse $\mod n.$ That should generalize.

Comment: Thanks, but how is this a bijection? Or even a single valued map? In your example, a given pair $(e,c)$ would appear many times.

Comment: @BalázsPozsgay No, there are 16 $5$-tuples and and if you look at positions $5$ and $3$ , in other words , $(e,c)$, each of the $16$ possibilities appears exactly once.

Comment: Yes, I see now! This is great now, such tables would give examples also for my more complicated case with 3+3 elements. Do you know a good reference for how to construct such solutions?

Comment: I think these arrays will give many good solutions for my problem. But not all. The condition for the orthogonal array is more restrictive than what I need. I just have a selection for possible sets of collumns for which the property should hold. I don't require that it holds for any pair or any triplet of column. Thanks in any case this is very useful!!